# Unable to set tab width to 4 in prettier

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I installed prettier extension for vscode and configured tab width as 4 spaces but it still indents new lines with 2 spaces. Anything I am doing wrong?

[image]

Here is the gif showing when I format the file:

[image]

**EDIT**:
Contents of **.prettierrc** file:

```
{
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "**/lwc/**/*.html",
      "options": { "parser": "lwc" }
    },
    {
      "files": "*.{cmp,page,component}",
      "options": { "parser": "html" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: do you also have a `.prettierrc` file in your project, and if so, what does it contain?

Comment: @NSjonas yes. Updated question with contents of the file.

Comment: I only use the `.prettierrc` file and I don't seem to have any issues. Try adding `"tabWidth": 4,`.  You might also check the "Workspace Settings" to make sure you aren't overwriting the user settings displayed in your answer.

Comment: @NSjonas  I did the "format document" and see this info dialog from prettier (https://imgur.com/YYxhWCf) and now my `.prettierrc` file shrunk to just two lines `{"tabWidth": 4,"useTabs": true}` and it is working fine. Looks like prettier 3.0 fixed it or made it easy. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Using `"tabWidth": 4,` in `.prettierrc` inside my project fixed the issue for me! Thanks, @nsjonas !!!

Comment: @AqeebImtiazHarun Was that "tabWidth" or "prettier.tabWidth"?

Comment: @JamesPoulose it was just `tabWidth` for me in `.prettierrc` in the root of the project. For VS Code settings.json it was `prettier.tabWidth`

Comment: Wanted to also add for anyone else who may come across this that even with updating the prettier settings, there may be a `.editorconfig` that could override any of the settings.

Comment: I just restarted VSCode (close/open) and it works fine now. 

Answer (score 56):

First, remove any `.prettierrc` from the working directory. Because it overrides user settings and uses the default values.

Second, set `Prettier: Tab Width` to 4.

Third, Unchecked `Prettier: Use Tabs`

And if you have to use `.prettierrc` file then specify all the options.

```
{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 80,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "proseWrap": "always",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "requireConfig": false,
    "useTabs": false,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
    "semi": true
}
```

Comment: hey,@mahbub-ul-islam, I have used this file. But when I changed this value VScode doesn't load the latest change from this file. Why this problem ?

Comment: I think `editor.formatOnSave` does not belong to `.prettierrc`. It should belong to vscode?

Answer (score 10):

Non of these possibilities solved my *VS Code* case with *Prettier*.

But the Prettier website show me how to do it!

This section (https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tab-width) sent me to `.editorconfig` website (https://editorconfig.org/):

I found this `.editorconfig` file at root folder of my project, and it had two specific configs that I changed.

Before

```
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

After

```
 indent_style = tab
 indent_size = 4
```

And finally it worked out!

Comment: Lifesaver.  I just uninstalled the extension and deleted the .editorconfig file.  A tab space of two I understand with HTML, but I just can't see code if the tabsize isn't four spaces.  Heck I used to know people that would use eight spaces!

Comment: yes you're right.

Comment: Also note that if you have an .editorconfig in a parent folder VS might use it (that's was the issue in my case)

Comment: Sadly enough did nothing for me. And the weirdest thing about is is that within the same folder, both files same extension, one file is indented correctly another isn't.

Answer (score 8):

I think it was because, `tabWidth:4` was specified in user's settings, while in workspace setting nothing was specified, so it uses default value for workspace i.e. `tabWidth:2`

as mentioned in comments also adding `tabWidth:2` in `.prettier.js` would fix it!

Check out about `tabWidth` option in [documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tab-width)

Comment: The problem is at indent_style = tab/space as soon as you change to space it formats to 4!

Answer (score 6):

Disable "use Tabs" option. Hopefully it will start working properly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It took me 3 hours to finally figure it out.

1. Make sure that the spaces/tab at the bottom is set to 4.
2. Tab size in settings is set to 4.
3. Prettier: Use Tabs is checked. (at least it worked for me)
4. Also try checking/unchecking Editor: detect indentation.

[Editor: Detect Indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJtYa.png)
[Prettier use tabs & tab size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIIo2.png)

Answer (score 1):

How I fixed it myself:

1. I found an extension that I was not aware of (maybe pack installed): Editor config.
2. I figured out it messed up my setting for tab and other stuff, so I deleted it.
3. Uncheck 'Use User Setting' in prettier.
4. Check all tab config, prettier config.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had a file named `prettier.config.js` in my root directory. I added `tabWidth` to it and it fixed the problem. Below are the contents of this file:

```
// prettier.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require("prettier-plugin-tailwindcss")],
  tabWidth: 4,
};
```

This file basically overrides the default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

That's the **user level** setting.

However some project make have **project level** setting which overwrites the user level, in file `.prettierrc`

```
{
  ******
  "tabWidth": 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the user settings `cmd shift p` then search for `user settings`
2. Add the following at the bottom of the file: `"editor.tabSize": 4`