# How to adjust prettier in vs code for 4 spaces and tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

I have the latest version of prettier on macos with latest vs code, but I still see 2 spaces on new tabs when I `Format Document`. This is a React/NextJS JSX document (also does with CSS).

[image]

In the VS Code Prettier settings, I have the tabs set as true and the spaces set at 4. I am not sure how to adjust this as I don't want the 2 lines as they appear to close together for me to see. How do I adjust this?

**EDIT [SOLVED]:**

The issue was that the page in VS needed to be closed and opened again after the changes. The pages got stuck. Thanks for the tips. I also used the previous SO answer to setup the proper settings prior to this post.

Comment: This answer might help you mate https://stackoverflow.com/a/68628930/17637655

Answer (score 2):

simple,
you need change settings

```
File -> Preferences -> Settings -> search for: "Prettier:Tab Width" -> change value to 4
```

Answer (score 1):

In the footer of VS Code there is an option to change your indents. It's next to the current cursor location. I don't know if that's what you're looking for.

[image: VS Code Footer]

Comment: Thanks, I need to close the page and reopen it for it to take affect. Great tip about the footer.